# JavaFX bindContentBidirectional of different types of Lists

Tags: java, binding, javafx, bind

If you have two different Lists.

```
ObservableList<File>
ObservableList<Node>
```

or just

```
ObservableList<A>
ObservableList<B>
```

How do you bind it together? Is there any transform or something like that?

Thank you.

> Referal - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29320895/1347177

Comment: You cannot perform a `ContentBidirectional` binding on ObservableList's of different types.

Comment: Is There any way how to bind UI list and my custom list together?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? May be if you let us know what you are trying to achieve, there may be an alternate approach to it.

Comment: I have list of Files, As datasource. Vbox list of ImageViews and TableView. I would like to add new file to datasource and have synchronized these lists. I hoped that binding could helps.

Comment: Do you want to add a new `ImageView` to the `VBox` for every file added to the `list of Files`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. An to the Table as well. Theres a little bit problém, cause I have own table item class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the `change` in the `ObservableList` of `Files` and for each new addition add a corresponding `ImageView` to the `VBox`.

I have create an example in which I have an `ObservableList` of String, which is a list of `URL of images`. On the button click I add a new URL(the address being the same) to the list. I have a `ListChangeListener` which listens to the addition of Strings and adds an `ImageView` to the `VBox` for it.

I am listening to `Addition`. You can add for `Removal` as well.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private final String IMAGE_PATH = "http://i.imgur.com/fcn1bFx.jpg";
    private final ObservableList<String> listOfImages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.setSpacing(10);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button button = new Button("Add");
        button.setOnAction( e -> {
            listOfImages.add(IMAGE_PATH);
        });
        listOfImages.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) c -> {
            c.next();
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                box.getChildren().add(0, new ImageView(c.getAddedSubList().get(0)));
            }
        });
        box.heightProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            pane.setVvalue(pane.getVmax());
        });

        box.getChildren().add(button);
        pane.setContent(box);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This is *not a bi-directional binding* but will fill in your needs.

Moreover, you can also add Listeners to the `VBox` and do corresponding changes to the `ObservableList`.

```
box.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>() {
     @Override
     public void onChanged(Change<? extends Node> c) {
         c.next();
         if(c.wasRemoved()){
              listOfImages.remove(c.getList().get(0));
         }
     }
});
```